# is a web service an actor in UML?

Tags: uml, use-case

i've a web project (e-commerce, buy and sell stuff) where a user can use three external services:

1. Google OpenID (admin authentification)
2. Facebook. (publish site news, but only in the site official page's wall)
3. Amazon. (make price comparaison).

since they're **"external"** to the application, are they considred as **actors**? i got this problem when i specify their roles in **use case**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are actors. All external entities that interact with the application you are modeling are actors.

Comment: but then how to declare them? what are their activities? because for exemple Facebook, it's not the user who will write the notification, it's the system that will send to the wall that some user has done something!

Comment: Model one use case for every interaction of your system with the external system (i.e. Facebook). The user doesn't have to be an actor in this use case.

Comment: so in specifying the roles of actors, in facebook, i'll only say: publish users discounts? and then i'll use the OAuth sequence diagram?

Comment: thank you :)
so i have a lot of work to do (google openid, facebook oauth, amazon api....)

Comment: If you have common use-cases for each system you can use the `<<include>>` use case to reduce their amount.

Comment: ah, i see! thank you :) sorry if am slow in UML, because am from those who hate it, i love program without making any schema! it's like making a movie without making a story board, the uml here is to write something to the teachers :(